# How to solve EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in read_scores function when using getc?

Tags: c

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)

```
List *read_scores(char *filename)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char c;
  size_t lines = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int bufferLength = 255;
  char buffer[bufferLength];

  fp = fopen(filename, "r");

  while (c != EOF)
  {
    if (c == '\n')
    {
      lines++;
    }
    c = getc(fp);
  }
  rewind(fp);
```

I keep having this problem with c=getc(fp) and can't find a solution. Im really new to this so any idea would be helpful

Comment: Why not `fgetc()`? Also `c` should be `int` so you can detect EOF.

Comment: You don't check the result of `fopen()` which could be bad.

Comment: And you should not test the value of `c` before the first assignment to it.

Comment: Consider assigning some kind of default value to *every* variable you declare as a matter of habit. Don't leave them bare. You can do things like move `FILE* fp` down to where you open the file so it's abundantly clear it's initialized. Like John points out, you use `c` before it has a value. It should be `int c = 0` to fix this. C is one of those languages where a tiny, trivial mistake can lead to a whole world of hurt down the road, so you *must* be disciplined.

Comment: There are many ways this code can violate memory. You need to post [mcve].

Comment: Another thing to note is this approach of clawing through the file character by character is silly. Just use `fgets()` which reads a whole line, or alternatively, if you're just scanning for newline characters to count lines, read in blocks of a fixed size like 1024 bytes, scan, and count.

Comment: Maybe try printing out the value of `c` ?  Also try making sure that it's not trying to access unallocated memory